# A generic error occurred in GDI+ upon calling Bitmap bt = new Bitmap(ms);

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have a Console Application that creates .TIFF files using values from "photo (image, null)" from database.

I've been processing thousands of records to create .TIFF files. Unfortunately, some records failed to create .TIFF files due to below error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was caught
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
       at Dims.Program.CreateTiff(DataRow dRow, String& imageFile, String fname_time_scan, String directory, String& remarks) in c:\Users\t-mntorres\Desktop\FOLDERS\Dims\Dims\Program.cs:line 190
  InnerException:
```

Here is my code:

```
object photo = GetPhoto(dRow);//sample value would be 0x49492A00080000001300FE0004000100000002000000000....
                if (photo != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    byte[] img = (byte[])photo;
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    ms.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
                    Bitmap bt = new Bitmap(ms);//Exception is thrown here
                    bt.Save("D:\files\test_image.tiff", ImageFormat.Tiff);
                }
```

Question: What could I be missing here? It works fine on other records. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: GDI+ have some troubles with memory when your image too big. Are you compile your application for `x86` or `x64` platform? Try to change to `x64` could help.

Comment: can u check the permissions on the records that fail? do u have the correct permissions?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I cannot change it to x64 for my machine is currently operating under x32 platform.

Comment: Meghaa - I can say that I have the correct permissions, both on database and on the .TIFFs destination path.

Comment: Well, it does sound as if the problem is with the image files. Did you find anything special about them (size, bit depth, pages, compression..) that makes them stand out?